# Difference between MVC 3 View Master Page (ASPX) and Master Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, master-pages

What is the difference between MVC 3 View Master Page (ASPX) and Master Page. I am working on asp.net MVC 3 project which mainly uses razor view engine but to integrate SSRS reports I need to add Aspx page. I want my reports to have same layout as cshtml pages in my project. 
Which master page should I add to my project and why?

Comment: I did not understand your question completely because I never worked with ASPX. Are you looking for [Layout](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the base class:

- A classic WebForms MasterPage derives from the [`System.Web.UI.MasterPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.masterpage.aspx) class.
- An ASP.NET MVC MasterPage (if you are using the WebForms view engine) derives from the [`System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewmasterpage.aspx) class which in turn derives from `System.Web.UI.MasterPage` but it adds additional properties such as `Model`, `Html`, `Ajax`, `Url`, `TempData`, `ViewBag`, ... so that you have access to MVC specific artifacts.

Inside an ASP.NET MVC application you should use the `System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage` class if you need to access all those MVC specific notions.

Answer (score 0):

Master Page is introduced in ASP.NET 2.0 and View Master Page is used in an ASP.NET MVC application.
View Master Page have a different base class and it can access to the helpers and can be strongly typed to a model (in MVC).